# Eclipse SWT Maintaining Same layout in 2 separate composites

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

[image]

Hello Everyone,

I have 2 Groups and each group has 3 Label and Text combinations, as you can see from the above Image.
I would like the text field to grab as much as space possible.hence, I have used grab 'true' only for the text field. 
These label and text fields are well aligned inside their own group/composite.

But, when these 2 Groups are considered as a whole, the label and text fields are out of alignment.

Is there a way to align these label and text fields across multiple Groups?

is there a way to align these labels and text fields, without declaring each groups having equal column width, and specifying the number of columns label and text fields occupy?

Below is the code I have used for creating the below groups.

```java
private void createFirstGroup(Composite parent) {
    Group firstGroup = new Group(parent, SWT.NONE);
    firstGroup.setText("first group");
    GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, false).applyTo(firstGroup);
    GridLayoutFactory.fillDefaults().numColumns(2).equalWidth(false).applyTo(firstGroup);
    String[] labels = new String[]{"Kwd","Variable","Value"};
    for(int index=0;index<labels.length; index++){
        Label label = new Label(firstGroup, SWT.NONE);
        label.setText(labels[index]);
        GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().applyTo(label);

        Text textField = new Text(firstGroup, SWT.BORDER);
        GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, false).applyTo(textField);
    }
  }
```

```java
private void createSecondGroup(Composite parent) {
    Group secondGroup = new Group(parent, SWT.NONE);
    secondGroup.setText("second group");
    GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, false).applyTo(secondGroup);
    GridLayoutFactory.fillDefaults().numColumns(2).equalWidth(false).applyTo(secondGroup);
    String[] labels = new String[]{"Count","Upper Comment","Lower Comment"};
    for(int index=0;index<labels.length; index++){
        Label label = new Label(secondGroup, SWT.NONE);
        label.setText(labels[index]);
        GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().applyTo(label);

        Text textField = new Text(secondGroup, SWT.BORDER);
        GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, false).applyTo(textField);
    }
  }
```

Comment: No. The layout in the two groups is independent and there is no way to link them.

Comment: Ah Okay @greg-449 :) Thank you for your answer :)